# How to remove ion-skeleton after getting data from a http request?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ion-skeleton for rendering placeholder content, in my case a list of users.
So I have:

```
<div class = "loading-users" *ngIf = "!users.length > 0">
    <ion-list  *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">     
      <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
          <ion-skeleton-text animated></ion-skeleton-text>
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
          <div>
            <ion-skeleton-text animated style="width: 80%"></ion-skeleton-text>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top:20px;">
            <ion-skeleton-text animated style="width: 50%"></ion-skeleton-text>
          </div>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>  
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

All good, it's showing the skeleton. But since I am getting this users list from a subscription to a http request, I need to wait for this request, till I don't have a response I want the skeleton to be there, if the response is more than 0 it will display my users, but how can I show another div saying "No users found" in case the response is equal to 0?

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you updating your users immutably after getting the response from the subscription?

Comment: no it keeps updating thanks to the observer. I have an <ion-list *ngFor = "let user of users$ | async"> , where users is got from the subscription. I'd like to wait for the request and in case the response is 0 show "no users found"

Comment: i do not understand it completely. please post you .ts file also

Comment: I have this in my .ts file: this.users$ = this.userservice.._updatedUsers;
    this.users$.subscribe(users=>{
    })

Comment: this behavior is weird i need to see the whole thing (.ts and .html) to have an idea what is going on.